# How to change the font size in tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am using `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename` in Python to select a file. How do I change the font size for the file list displayed? I have found answers on StackOverflow on how to change the font of some items on the display (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655418/tkfiledialog-asksaveasfile-text-color-font)), but do not know the name of the `ttk` widget that is used for the file list.

Comment: I don't think `askopenfilename` gives that kind of control. The answer to that linked question which attempts to use a `ttk.Style` wouldn't work because `filedialog`s have nothing to do with `ttk` widgets (note how the `Style` created in never used after it's configured). You should be able to do what you want by creating your own dialog widget that internally used a [`tkinter.Listbox`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190323174019id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html) which does support a `font` option.

Comment: You might find the answers to the question [Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057672/correct-way-to-implement-a-custom-popup-tkinter-dialog-box) useful in creating your own dialog class.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. Modifying `TkDefaultFont` changes the font of the buttons and labels around the file list, but does not affect the file list itself. On my high density display, the file list uses a tiny font, I need to stick my nose in the monitor to read it.